# How to change file extension in php

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is the problem I am going through explained below:

1) When I click on TAB say **“blog”** the URL shows **xxxxxx/blog.php**

2) When I click on a topic **inside a blog say “shopping”** the URL shows **xxxx/shopping.php**

In my first problem, I want to remove the **.php extension** from the URL and want it to show like this **xxxxxx/blog** instead of this **xxxxxx/blog.php**

In my second problem, I not only want to remove the **.php extension** from the URL but I also want the URL to show the path like this; **xxxxx/blog/shopping** instead of showing only this **xxxx/shopping.php**

```
<?php

include("company_profile/lib/data.config.php");

// if id exists in URL
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
$page = (int)$_GET['id'];
}
else
{
$page = '';
}

// limit of pages shown
$limit = 5;

// if page is not empty
if($page == '')
{
$page = 1;
$start = 0;
}
else
{
$start=$limit*($page-1);
}

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM blog order by id desc LIMIT            $start, $limit");

$tot = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM blog");
$total = mysqli_num_rows($tot);
$num_page = ceil($total/$limit);

// function of pagination that showing number of pages
function pagination($page, $num_page)
{
echo'<ul style="list-style-type:none;">';

for($i=1;$i<=$num_page;$i++)
{
if($i==$page)
{
echo'<li class="pagination-button">'.$i.'</li>';
}
else
{
// <a href="http://example.com/blog/?id='.$i.'">  this is IMPORTANT your url to blog posts
echo'<li class="pagination-button"><a href="http://localhost/soft/arif.php?    id='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
}
}

echo'</ul>';
}


?>
```

Comment: you will need to go through .htacess, [re-write url with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Comment: ys i have already create .htaccess file  and i have done code like this

Comment: my code is  RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)\$ $1.php

Comment: you will need to handle your routes then, you may use a router or write your own if you want to make a customized router

Comment: i didn't understand can explain more

Comment: Read the [tag:mod_rewrite] [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mod-rewrite/info)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: still i am getting same url